# Drawing syllable diagrammes in LaTeX

Tags: linguistics

I'd like to know how to best draw syllable structure diagrammes like the following image in LaTex.

[image]

I have tried using tikz-qtree, but found that it doesn't support multiple roots, and I have tried to use tkz-graph, but found that it doesn't support non-ASCII vertex labels (e.g. $\sigma$ doesn't work). Neither support the C--V lines that we see in the image above.

Using plain tikz produces something ok:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={sibling distance=2\baselineskip}}
\node (s1) at (2,0) {$\sigma$} ;
\node (s2) at (5,0) {$\sigma$} ;
\node (s3) at (8,0) {$\sigma$} ;
\node (c1) at (1,-1) {C} ;
\node (v1) at (3,-1) {V} ;
\node (c2) at (4,-1) {C} ;
\node (v2) at (5,-1) {V} ;
\node (c3) at (6,-1) {C} ;
\node (c4) at (7,-1) {C} ;
\node (v3) at (8,-1) {V} ;
\node (c5) at (9,-1) {C} ;
\node (l1) at (1,-2) {ɬ} ;
\node (l2) at (3,-2) {ə} ;
\node (l3) at (4,-2) {w} ;
\node (l4) at (5,-2) {a} ;
\node (l5) at (6,-2) {w} ;
\node (l6) at (7,-2) {n} ;
\node (l7) at (8,-2) {ə} ;
\node (l8) at (9,-2) {n} ;
\draw (c1) -- (s1) ;
\draw (v1) -- (s1) ;
\draw (c2) -- (s2) ;
\draw (v2) -- (s2) ;
\draw (c3) -- (s2) ;
\draw (c4) -- (s3) ;
\draw (v3) -- (s3) ;
\draw (c5) -- (s3) ;

\draw (c1) -- (l1) ;
\draw[dotted] (v1) -- (l2) ;
\draw (c2) -- (l3) ;
\draw (v2) -- (l4) ;
\draw (c3) -- (l5) ;
\draw (c4) -- (l6) ;
\draw (v3) -- (l7) ;
\draw (c5) -- (l8) ;


\draw (c1) -- (v1) -- (c2) -- (v2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (v3) -- (c5) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces:

[image]

But there are one remaining issues:

1. It would be good to have the space between the CV and CVC to be the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the node names to draw the lines, e.g. `\draw (s1) -- (c1);`

Comment: That's great! I'll update the post. Thanks! :)

Comment: See e.g. [Autosegmental Representation in tikz-qtree](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/240361). btw I've never seen the horizontal lines between elements. Is there a published source for this sort of representation?

Comment: By the way, as you've specified the coordinates of every node explicitly, changing the spacing is just a matter of changing the coordinates. Move `c1` and `l1` to x=2 (they are currently at x=1), and `s1` to x=2.5 (currently at x=2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel there are probably more elegant ways of doing this, but you can do it with `tikz-qtree`. Below I used three `\Tree`s inside the same `tikzpicture`, with the two last ones shifted right. The horizontal connections between the Cs and Vs are made manually, by making them named nodes and using `\draw`.

I did not add the proper symbols in the leaves, as I don't know what is required to make them work. And looking at the screenshot, the amount of shifting could be fine tuned a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  sibling distance=1em
]
\Tree[.$\sigma$ [.\node(c1){C}; [.n ] ] [.\node(v1) {V}; [.e ] ] ]

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\Tree[.$\sigma$ [.\node(c2){C}; [.n ] ] [.\node(v2) {V}; \edge[dashed]; [.e ] ] [.\node(c3){C}; [.e ] ] ]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
\Tree[.$\sigma$ [.\node(c4){C}; [.n ] ] [.\node(v3) {V}; [.e ] ] [.\node(c5){C}; [.e ] ] ]
\end{scope}

\draw (c1) -- (v1) -- (c2) -- (v2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (v3) -- (c5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```